# How to include emoji in error messages in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add robot emoji in my error message. I tried it by using `` throw new Error(`${robot} It seems you have not added a valid cloud provider`); ``. However, it's not working. Is there any way to print the latter error message with robot emoji?

Comment: what is `robot`? do you have it set equal to the literal emoji `''`? (seems to work fine if you've done it this way)

Comment: Nope, I did not set it rather included it directly in the error message

Comment: What's wrong with just `throw new Error(' It seems you have not added a valid cloud provider')`…?

Comment: @deceze yep that's better. Thanks. Actually tried to do that first but instead of emoji got as 'robot' as text.

Comment: @Dominic What do HTML entities have to do with Javascript string literals?!

Comment: console.log(“\ud83d\ude0e”)

Comment: @deceze console.log("&#x1F916");  works

Comment: @Dominic Define "works". It logs "&#x1F916"…

Comment: @deceze environment encoding format matters, i don't intended for you to actually log it. Try on a utf-8 web page

Comment: @Dominic With all due respect, *you'll* need to demonstrate how it's supposed to work. What you show literally doesn't work.

Comment: @deceze my apologies, you're correct, i taught his concern was just to output an emoji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const robot = '';
throw new Error(`${robot} It seems you have not added a valid cloud provider`);
```